# XPath Invalid Expression

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

```
<?php
  $feed = file_get_contents('http://thexmofo.wordpress.com/feed/');
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($feed);
  $xml->registerXPathNamespace('media', 'http://thexmofo.wordpress.com/feed/');
  $images = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/item/media:content@url');
  var_dump($images);
?>
```

Can anyone tell my why I'm getting `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: Invalid expression` followed by `bool(false)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That XPath expression is invalid, that much we know. Now since you didn't say what you were trying to select, all we can do is randomly guess your intentions, so here's my random guess:

```
/rss/channel/item/media:content/@url
```

...assuming you're trying to select all the @url attributes in that feed.

Comment: Josh you guessed... not so randomly since I had made what looks to me like a very close attempt... correctly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `bool(false)` is probably from your `var_dump`.

Iam not sure if `media:content@url` is valid xpath...